# Getting value of drop down list JavaScript

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

How to make that the all selected options, not the values, but the actual text, would be displayed somewhere?

Html:

```
<h1>Made your PC:</h1>

<div>
  <label>Processeor: </label><select id="processor" name="processor">
  <option class="label" value>Select Processor</option>
  <!-- Home Ware -->
  <option value="P1">Processor 1</option>
  <option value="P2">Processor 2</option>
  <option value="P3">Processor 3</option>
  <option value="P4">Processor 4</option>

  </select>
</div>

<p><strong>Only compatible components will show.</strong></p>
<div>
  <label>Select motherboard: </label><select id="motherboard" name="motherboard" class="subcat" disabled="disabled">
  <option class="label" value>Select Motherboard</option>
  <!-- Home Ware -->
  <option rel="P1 P2" value="AS1">ASUS RAMPAGE V EXTREME</option>
  <option rel="P2 P3" value="AS2">ASUS ATX DDR3 2600 LGA</option>
  <option rel="P1 P3 P4" value="GB1">Gigabyte AM3+</option>
  <option rel="P2 P4" value="MSI1">MSI ATX DDR3 2600 LGA 1150</option>

  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <label>Select RAM: </label> <select disabled="disabled" class="subcat" id="RAM" name="RAM">
  <option class="label" value>RAM Memory</option>
  <option rel="AS1 AS2 GB1" value="KI1">Kingston Value RAM</option>
  <option rel="AS1 AS2 MSI1" value="P5KPL">P5KPL-AM SE</option>
  <option rel="MSI1 GB1" value="960GM">960GM-VGS3 FX </option>
  </select>
</div>

<div>
  <label>Select Video Board: </label> <select disabled="disabled" class="subcat" id="video-card" name="video-card">
  <option class="label" value>Video Card</option>
  <option rel="MSI1 AS2" value="EVGA8400">EVGA GeForce 8400 GS</option>
  <option rel="AS1" value="XFXAMD">XFX AMD Radeon HD 5450</option>
  <option rel="MSI1 GB1" value="GTX750Ti">EVGA GeForce GTX 750Ti SC</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function(){


  var $supcat = $("#processor"),
      $cat = $("#motherboard"),
      $subcat = $(".subcat");


  $supcat.on("change",function(){
    var _rel = $(this).val();
    $cat.find("option").attr("style","");
    $cat.val("");
    if(!_rel) return $cat.prop("disabled",true);
    $cat.find("[rel~='"+_rel+"']").show();
    $cat.prop("disabled",false);
  });

  $cat.on("change",function(){
    var _rel = $(this).val();
    $subcat.find("option").attr("style","");
    $subcat.val("");
    if(!_rel) return $subcat.prop("disabled",true);
    $subcat.find("[rel~='"+_rel+"']").show();
    $subcat.prop("disabled",false);
  });
});
```

I tried this one code that was posted earlier, but it only display one selection, right after picking, is there any way it could display all the selections and with my random text, like "Your selections"?:

```
<script>
    function myNewFunction(sel)
    {
        alert(sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text);
    }
</script>

<select id="box1" onChange="myNewFunction(this);" >
    <option value="98">dog</option>
    <option value="7122">cat</option>
    <option value="142">bird</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Doesn't work how? Seems to work here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNdzMb

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, it does work, but i need to display all the selections, it display one, right after picking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give the actual label text, not the value, for a given select-element.

```
$(selector).find(":checked").html()
```

So if you want to show all of them, you could do something like this:

```
$("#video-card").on("change", function () {
    var choices = [];
  $("select").each(function() {
    choices.push($(this).find(":checked").html());
  });
  alert("You selected: " + choices.join(', '));
})
```

And here's a codepen for demo purposes

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbjKYQ

Comment: Is it possible to launch it after everything is chosen, or some button to trigger it? It pop ups right after i select.

Comment: It works great! Is it possible to make a a button to trigger it, so it would not pop up every time a selection is made? And is it possible to write something there like "this is your selections:"?

Comment: Yes, just select your last select instead of all of them, I updated my post and the codepen to reflect this

Comment: That's it! Thanks. Is it possible to write something on that pop out?

Comment: Edited my answer to write "You selected:"

Comment: How to add the code from codepen? This one works `$("#video-card").on("change", function () {
    var choices = [];
  $("select").each(function() {
    choices.push($(this).find(":checked").html());
  });
  alert("You selected: " + choices.join(', '));
})`

Comment: But i cant to make the one from codepen to work. You need to add it another way?

Answer (score 0):

```
function myNewFunction(sel) {
    alert($(sel).val());
}
```

This should actually be working.
If that doesn't work, try to place a `window.setTimeout(function() { ... }, 10);` around your alert. It's possible that the browser calls the myNewFunction() method before it updates the selection value when the user clicks on one option.

**EDIT:** If you want the text instead of the value, use

```
alert($(sel).find("option:selected").text());
```

Comment: It does work, but it display the value of the selection, not the text.

Comment: I changed my post a little.

Comment: It does work now, is it possible to display all the selections? This one displays only one, right after picking. And is it possible to write something on that display, like "Your selections are:"?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? The purpose of the `select` tag is that only one option can be selected. How do you want to select multiple?

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through each of the selects, not just the first one:

```
function updateOutput() {
  var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('SELECT');
  var output = document.getElementById('output');
  var arr = [];

  for (i=0; i < selects.length; i++) {
    arr.push(selects[i].options[selects[i].selectedIndex].text);
  }

  output.innerHTML = arr.join('; ');
  return arr;
}
```

In this case, I push all the values into an array and then join the array values at the end to create the final string.

I updated a codepen provided earlier: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvGxgz